# native dependencies don't get copied to their destination in flutter plugin

Tags: flutter, android-ndk, flutter-plugin

I'm creating a Flutter Plugin that uses native libraries. The problem I am facing is, The native dependencies I added don't get copied to Android's `context.nativeLibraryDir`. Following are my configurations.

This is my file structure for the `android` folder of the plugin (not the example app).
[image: File Structure]

In the `build.gradle` of my the plugin, I have the following. I also tried added `jni.srcDirs = []` after researching, but it didn't work either.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
       jniLibs.srcDirs += 'src/main/jniLibs'
       java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}
```

I think all of the above is correct, because the following is my APK (of the example app) that is built, and it has the libraries.
[image: Apk analysis]

But after the example app is installed (on Android x86 Emulator, also tested on arm64 device), It crashes when I try to execute the native libs, I want to use them as executables (It worked in a standalone android project, now I just copied the libs & some code in the plugin)

[image: no libs found]

The interesting thing I found, flutter's `libflutter.so` don't get copied either which I guess is required for proper functionality. The app should crash without `libflutter.so`, but it doesn't.

I have also tried adding `ndk.abiFilters` to the example app's `build.gradle` but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the same problem and found the following solution in my case (Flutter plugin with native libs):

android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<application
  android:extractNativeLibs="true"
  ...
>
...
```

Details:

Since Android 6.0 system libs can be stored uncompressed within the APK and do not have to be extracted and stored somewhere else (https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/smallerapk-part-8-native-libraries-open-from-apk-fc22713861ff). Loading system libs within the APK is supported through (Java):

```
static { System.loadLibrary(..); }
```

see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#loadLibrary(java.lang.String).

If an extraction of the system libs for the Flutter plugin is required (e.g. because you cannot just build upon `System.loadLibrary`), one can use the `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` in the plugin's Manifest application element (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element).

Important to note, that the DSL way of doing it (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=ndk-build#compress-native-libs-dsl) doesn't work in my case (Flutter plugin).